# Morphisms of Banach spaces

Tags: banach-spaces, homological-algebra, terminology, reference-request

What is the standard name in English for bounded linear maps $f:E\to F$ between Banach spaces such that the kernel $\ker(f)$ has a complement, and $\text{im}(f)$ is closed, and has a complement?

Apparently, when $f$ is injective or surjective, it is sometimes referred to as an admissible monomorphism or epimorphism, respectively. Is this terminology standard?

Comment: In Helemskii's work on Banach (Co)Homology, this is the terminology he uses.  I would consider it standard, in the sense that I'd use it, but I think I'd always be tempted to define what was meant.  Theo's answer suggests that it's not standard if your audience is sufficiently large.

Comment: Dear Ezra, As a somewhat related terminological remark, I think that Bourbaki (in his book *Topological vector spaces*) uses the terminology *strict* for a morphism with closed image.    I don't know if this continues to be standard terminology for current researchers on archimedean Banach spaces, but I can say that it *is* standard for number theorists working with $p$-adic Banach spaces.  Regards, Matt  

Comment: Seconding Emerton's comment: in categories with kernels and cokernels (and hence images and coimages) I have seen strict morphisms defined as those $f$ for which the canonical map from Coimage(f) to Image(f) is an isomorphism. (I came across this in work of Schneiders and Prosmans, but I don't know where the term originated.)

Comment: @Emerton, @Yemon: Since this topic was brought up, I think if anyone is to be credited for this notion then it should be A. Weil who, as far as I know, introduced them in his book on integration in topological groups in the mid-thirties.

Answer (score 10):

I don't know if there's a universally accepted name for this notion. Of course, if the kernel and the complement of the image are finite-dimensional, such a map is a Fredholm operator. I would suggest to call them pseudo-invertible (in reference to the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse), because $f:E \to F$ has complemented kernel and image if and only if there is a $g:F \to E$ such that $fgf = f$ (and $gfg = g$).

Since the question is tagged homological algebra, let me point out that these morphisms are precisely the morphisms factoring as $E \twoheadrightarrow I \rightarrowtail F$, where $\twoheadrightarrow$ stands for a split epimorphism and $\rightarrowtail$ for a split monomorphism. These are the *admissible monomorphisms* and *admissible epimorphisms* for the *split exact structure* (in the sense of Quillen) on the additive category of Banach spaces and bounded linear maps, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_category) for more on this. However, there are several exact structures on the category of Banach spaces (at least three of interest), so admissible monomorphism/epimorphism alone is not good enough from this point of view.

I've seen several names for the maps you're asking about in the literature:

- In Borel-Wallach, *Continuous cohomology, discrete subgroups and representations of reductive groups*, Annals of Math. Studies **94**, Princeton University Press (1980), IX 1.5, they are called $s$-*morphisms* (actually for Hausdorff locally convex spaces).
- Guichardet, *Cohomologie des groupes topologiques et des algèbres de Lie*, Textes Mathématiques **2**, Fernand Nathan, Paris (1980), Appendice D, Def. D.1 calls them *strong* (again in the setting of Hausdorff locally convex spaces).
- Monod, *Continuous Bounded Cohomology of Locally Compact Groups*, Springer Lecture Notes in Mathematics, **1758** (2001), Definition 4.2.2, calls them *weakly admissible* (the weakly refers to the fact that his notion of admissibility requires that if $f$ is of norm $1$, there is a pseudo-inverse $g$ of norm $1$, at least for monomorphisms).

Comment: the condition that there exist a $g$ with $fgf=f$ and $gfg=g$ is sometimes called *regularity*, by analogy with von Neumann regular rings. 

I have also heard such an $f$ called *split* since, if $f$ is epi then this condition is equivalent to $f$ being split epi, while if $f$ is mono it is equivalent to $f$ being split mono.



Comment: I've seen the term split used for those $f$ for which there exists $g$ satisfying $fgf=f$ (this is used in Weibel's Homological Algebra book for instance)